# Modularizing Reactive Expressions in a Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny, module, shiny-reactivity

I'm currently working on refactoring my Shiny application to make use of modules for better structure and maintainability. The application involves a series of numeric input fields, the values of which are summed and displayed in a field labeled "ABC".

While the app functions as expected in its initial non-modularized state, after attempting to refactor it into modules, I'm encountering an issue with reactivity. Specifically, the "ABC" field, which should display the updated sum of all input fields, is not reflecting the changes reactively.

I suspect that I may not be passing arguments correctly between the UI and server modules, but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. I would appreciate any assistance to help improve and correct my code. Thank you!"

```
library(shiny)

# Function to generate numericInputs
createNumericInput <- function(region) {
  numericInput(region$id, region$label, min = 0, max = 3, step = 1, value = 0)
}

# List of inputs
input_details <- list(
  list(id = "A1", label = "0 A"),
  list(id = "B2", label = "1 B"),
  list(id = "C3", label = "2 C")
)

# ui module
name_UI <- function(id, numeric_inputs) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tags$div(
      id = "inline",
      fluidRow(
        h4("ABC"),
        column(width = 6,
               numeric_inputs,
               numericInput(ns("ABC"), "ABC", min = 0, max = 39, step = 1, value = 0)
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

# server module
name_server <- function(id, input_details) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    sum_reactive <- reactive({
      sum_values <- 0
      for(region in input_details) {
        input_id <- ns(region$id)
        val <- input[[input_id]]
        if (!is.null(val)) {
          sum_values <- sum_values + as.numeric(val)
        }
      }
      sum_values
    })
    
    # Update the value of ABC when the inputs change
    observe({
      updateNumericInput(session, ns("ABC"), value = sum_reactive())
    })
  })
}

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  name_UI("mod_1", lapply(input_details, createNumericInput)) # Apply createNumericInput to input_details here
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  name_server("mod_1", input_details)
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. When creating your numeric inputs via `lapply` you did not take care of the module's namespace, i.e. you did not create the inputs in the module namespace. To fix that I added a `ns` argument to `createNumericInput`. And of course could we then simply use e.g. `input[[region$id]]` to access the value of the input in the server. Using `ns(...)` will have no effect as just said you have not created the inputs in the module's namespace.
2. In the server part, in `updateNumericInput` you don't have to wrap the input id in `ns()` or as Hadley has put it in [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-modules.html#module-server)

   > Note that `moduleServer()` takes care of the namespacing automatically.

Note: I moved the creation of the numeric inputs via `lapply` inside the module UI and only pass the `input_details` list to the UI.

```
library(shiny)

# Function to generate numericInputs
createNumericInput <- function(region, ns = NULL) {
  id <- if (!is.null(ns)) ns(region$id) else region$id
  numericInput(id, region$label, min = 0, max = 3, step = 1, value = 0)
}

# List of inputs
input_details <- list(
  list(id = "A1", label = "0 A"),
  list(id = "B2", label = "1 B"),
  list(id = "C3", label = "2 C")
)

# ui module
name_UI <- function(id, numeric_inputs) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    tags$div(
      id = "inline",
      fluidRow(
        h4("ABC"),
        column(
          width = 6,
          lapply(input_details, createNumericInput, ns = ns),
          numericInput(ns("ABC"), "ABC", min = 0, max = 39, step = 1, value = 0)
        )
      )
    )
  )
}

# server module
name_server <- function(id, input_details) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns

    sum_reactive <- reactive({
      sum_values <- 0
      for (region in input_details) {
        val <- input[[region$id]]
        
        if (!is.null(val)) {
          sum_values <- sum_values + as.numeric(val)
        }
      }
      sum_values
    })

    observe({
      updateNumericInput(session, "ABC", value = sum_reactive())
    })
  })
}

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  name_UI("mod_1", input_details) # Apply createNumericInput to input_details here
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  name_server("mod_1", input_details)
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you know this: in a golem framework, where would you put `createNumericInput()` and `input_details`. I think of putting them into `golem_utils_ui.R` or putting both in the `module.R`. Thanks.

Comment: Hm. While I have had a look at `golem` I haven't really used it up to now. But I try to mimic the golem style for my apps too. So, if a function is a general one, which could be used in different modules then I would go for `utils_ui`. If it is specific to the module I would put it in `module.R`. In your case, if you use `createNumericInput` only in one module I would put in `module.R`. `input_details` is even more special. IMHO this should be put in a kind of config file or `globals.R`.

Comment: Perfect. You are one of the best, :-)